# SUM values across two multidimensional arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, addition

I have a problem how to SUM values of two multidimensional arrays in PHP.
Two arrays are storred in variables for example **$array_1** and **$array_2**

Both $array_1 and $array_2 have sub-arrays, which again have data stored in their respective arrays. Notice that data is organized as x-data and y-data, where y-data is just a DATE stamp.

I need to SUM x-data values of these two arrays $array_1 and $array_2, with respect to y-data (DATE) dimension. This is why it got tricky for me, the closes answers I have found have only numbers.

Example:

**$array_1**

```
Array
(
    [0] => object
        (
            [x-data] => Array
                (
                    [data1] => 0
                    [data2] => 1
                    [data3] => 2
                    [data4] => 3
                    [data5] => 4
                    [data6] => 5
                    [data7] => 6
                    [data8] => 7
                )

            [y-data] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 20141127
                )

        )

    [1] => object
        (
            [x-data] => Array
                (
                    [data1] => 2
                    [data2] => 4
                    [data3] => 6
                    [data4] => 8
                    [data5] => 10
                    [data6] => 12
                    [data7] => 14
                    [data8] => 16
                )

            [y-data] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 20141128
                )

        )

)
```

**$array_2**

```
Array
(
    [0] => object
        (
            [x-data] => Array
                (
                    [data1] => 0
                    [data2] => 1
                    [data3] => 2
                    [data4] => 3
                    [data5] => 4
                    [data6] => 5
                    [data7] => 6
                    [data8] => 7
                )

            [y-data] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 20141127
                )

        )

    [1] => object
        (
            [x-data] => Array
                (
                    [data1] => 0
                    [data2] => 1
                    [data3] => 2
                    [data4] => 3
                    [data5] => 4
                    [data6] => 5
                    [data7] => 6
                    [data8] => 7
                )

            [y-data] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 20141128
                )

        )

)
```

**$result = $array_1 + $array_2 should look like this:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => object
        (
            [x-data] => Array
                (
                    [data1] => 0
                    [data2] => 2
                    [data3] => 4
                    [data4] => 6
                    [data5] => 8
                    [data6] => 10
                    [data7] => 12
                    [data8] => 14
                )

            [y-data] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 20141127
                )

        )

    [1] => object
        (
            [x-data] => Array
                (
                    [data1] => 2
                    [data2] => 5
                    [data3] => 8
                    [data4] => 11
                    [data5] => 14
                    [data6] => 17
                    [data7] => 20
                    [data8] => 23
                )

            [y-data] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 20141128
                )

        )

)
```

I have tried some things, like foreach() inside foreach() but I got a multiplication effect of the array values (2 x 2 = 4 subarrays instead of 2).

Any help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a partial answer as this should only only work if $array1 and $array2 have same number of elements and have unique y-datas, and each of their x-data (with y-data in common) have the same number of elements.

```
$result = array_multisum($array1, $array2);

function array_multisum($array1, $array2)
{
    $newArray = array();
    foreach ($array1 as $object1) {
        $newObject = new stdClass();
        // find object in the 2nd array having the same data as current object
        foreach ($array2 as $object2) {
            // if object is found, sum the x-data with the current object 
            if ($object1->{'y-data'}['date'] === $object2->{'y-data'}['date']) {
                $newObject->{'x-data'} = data_sum($object1->{'x-data'}, $object2->{'x-data'});
                break;
            }
        }
        $newObject->{'y-data'} = $object1->{'y-data'};
        $newArray[] = $newObject;
    }
    return $newArray;
}

function data_sum($data1, $data2) 
{
    $newData = array();
    // sum up the values for each key
    foreach (array_keys($data1) as $key) {
        $newData[$key] = $data1[$key] + $data2[$key];
    }
    return $newData;
}
```

Comment: Hi Lynn, thanks for your answer, however, turns this is not so simple, if you look at how the array is constructed, parts 'object', 'x-data' and 'y-data' are generated by a class, simply putting those inside your function does not work and generates a lot of warnings and errors. I appreciate your help, but cannot test it properly and will have to drop this idea for now.